# Image file path in data property not showing until I open up the component in vue chrome dev tools

Tags: image, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to build an image preview system for an avatar:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="level">
            <img :src="avatar" width="50" height="50" class="mr-1">
        </div>

        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" accept="image/*" @change="onChange">
        </form>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                avatar: null,
                setAuthHeader: axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.$store.state.token,
            };
        },
        computed: {
            user() {
              return this.$store.state.user
            },
            avatar_path() {
                this.avatar = this.user.avatar_path
            },
        },
        methods: {
            onChange(e) {
                if (! e.target.files.length) return;
                let file = e.target.files[0];
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onload = e => {
                    this.avatar = e.target.result;
                    this.persist(file);
                };
            },
            persist(avatar) {
                let data = new FormData();
                data.append('avatar', avatar);
                this.setAuthHeader;
                axios.post(`/settings/avatar`, data)
                    .then(() => flash('Avatar uploaded!'));
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In my code the user computed property returns a JSON object from vuex which gets the object from local stroage.

What keeps happening is when I refresh the page that changes the profile image the default image doesn't show up. The element looks like this in chrome devtools:

`<img width="50" height="50" class="mr-1">`

When I open up vue dev tools, click on the component this functionality is in, the image src gets added:

`<img width="50" height="50" class="mr-1" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/avatars/default.png">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `avatar_path` computed property incorrectly:

- You shouldn't be modifying state in a computed property (you're assigning to `this.avatar`).
- Nothing is accessing `avatar_path` for it to be called. It's when you open Vue dev tools that the *dev tools code* accesses that property so it can display it in  the component data UI.

The best fix is to change `avatar` into a computed property like this:

```js
computed: {
  avatar() {
    if (this.user) {
      return this.user.avatar_path;
    } else {
      // Use a placeholder image URL
      return '/path/to/placeholder.png';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add my methods and was trying to do something close to that, but kept running into problems while trying to update the `this.avatar` `onChange(e)`

Comment: This is technically the right answer to how I framed the question. Should I mark this answer as correct and start a new question?

Comment: I won't hurt to ask a new question if it differs from this one (you'll get more responses).

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="level">
        <img :src="avatar" width="50" height="50" class="mr-1">
    </div>

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" @change="onChange">
    </form>

</div>
```

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            setAuthHeader: axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.$store.state.token,
        };
    },
    computed: {
        user() {
          return this.$store.state.user
        },
        avatar() {
            return this.user.avatar_path;
        },
    },
    methods: {

    }
}
```